# Xcode 9 won´t recognize identifier of a TableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift4, xcode9

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =  companyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

I get this Error: "Initialization of immutable value 'cell' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it."

I used "cell" as identifier for my TableViewCell. How can I fix it?

Comment: The mentioned *error* is a warning (yellow). There must be another real error (red) about a missing return value.

Comment: adding the missing `return cell` may help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message really says it all: you're assigning a value to the constant `cell` but never use that value.

Also, the function `tableView(:cellForRowAt:)` is declared as returning a UITableViewCell instance, which you never do.

Fixing both problems leads to this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    // do stuff with the cell
    return cell
}
```